# BASS 2.4.4 Error When Making

Tags: c++, makefile, bass

I'm trying to `make` the BASS 2.4.4 library for my Linux Ubuntu Hardy Heron, but when I run `make` I'm getting many errors, see:

```
[ubuntu@eeepc:~/Desktop/bass24-linux] make
make -C 3dtest
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/Desktop/bass24-linux/3dtest'
cc -Os -I/home/ubuntu/Desktop/bass24-linux -L/home/ubuntu/Desktop/bass24-linux -lbass -Wl,-rpath,/home/ubuntu/Desktop/bass24-linux `pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --cflags --libs` `pkg-config libglade-2.0 --cflags --libs` -export-dynamic -D'GLADE_PATH="/home/ubuntu/Desktop/bass24-linux/3dtest/"' 3dtest.c -o 3dtest
Package gtk+-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk+-2.0' found
Package libglade-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libglade-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libglade-2.0' found
3dtest.c:6:21: error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
3dtest.c:7:25: error: glade/glade.h: No such file or directory
3dtest.c:19: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
3dtest.c:20: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
3dtest.c:21: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
3dtest.c: In function ‘Error’:
3dtest.c:39: error: ‘GtkWidget’ undeclared (first use in this function)
3dtest.c:39: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
3dtest.c:39: error: for each function it appears in.)
3dtest.c:39: error: ‘dialog’ undeclared (first use in this function)
3dtest.c:39: error: ‘win’ undeclared (first use in this function)
3dtest.c:39: error: ‘GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
3dtest.c:40: error: ‘GTK_MESSAGE_ERROR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
3dtest.c:40: error: ‘GTK_BUTTONS_OK’ undeclared (first use in this function)
3dtest.c: At top level:
3dtest.c:47: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
3dtest.c: In function ‘UpdateButtons’:
3dtest.c:55: error: ‘glade’ undeclared (first use in this function)
3dtest.c: At top level:
3dtest.c:67: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘ListSelectionChange’
3dtest.c:83: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘FileExtensionFilter’
3dtest.c:88: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
3dtest.c:118: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
3dtest.c:133: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
3dtest.c:138: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
3dtest.c:143: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
3dtest.c:149: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
3dtest.c:155: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
3dtest.c:162: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
3dtest.c:169: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
3dtest.c:176: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘Update’
3dtest.c: In function ‘main’:
3dtest.c:251: error: ‘glade’ undeclared (first use in this function)
3dtest.c:253: error: ‘win’ undeclared (first use in this function)
3dtest.c:256: error: ‘ListSelectionChange’ undeclared (first use in this function)
3dtest.c:259: error: ‘GtkTreeView’ undeclared (first use in this function)
3dtest.c:259: error: ‘list’ undeclared (first use in this function)
3dtest.c:260: error: ‘GtkTreeViewColumn’ undeclared (first use in this function)
3dtest.c:260: error: ‘col’ undeclared (first use in this function)
3dtest.c:262: error: ‘GtkCellRenderer’ undeclared (first use in this function)
3dtest.c:262: error: ‘renderer’ undeclared (first use in this function)
3dtest.c:265: error: ‘GtkListStore’ undeclared (first use in this function)
3dtest.c:265: error: ‘liststore’ undeclared (first use in this function)
3dtest.c:265: error: ‘G_TYPE_STRING’ undeclared (first use in this function)
3dtest.c:271: error: ‘GtkFileFilter’ undeclared (first use in this function)
3dtest.c:271: error: ‘filter’ undeclared (first use in this function)
3dtest.c:272: error: ‘filesel’ undeclared (first use in this function)
3dtest.c:272: error: ‘GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN’ undeclared (first use in this function)
3dtest.c:273: error: ‘GTK_STOCK_CANCEL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
3dtest.c:273: error: ‘GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
3dtest.c:273: error: ‘GTK_STOCK_OPEN’ undeclared (first use in this function)
3dtest.c:273: error: ‘GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
3dtest.c:277: error: ‘GTK_FILE_FILTER_FILENAME’ undeclared (first use in this function)
3dtest.c:277: error: ‘FileExtensionFilter’ undeclared (first use in this function)
3dtest.c:290: error: ‘Update’ undeclared (first use in this function)
make[1]: *** [3dtest] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/Desktop/bass24-linux/3dtest'
make: *** [3dtest] Error 2
[ubuntu@eeepc:~/Desktop/bass24-linux]
```

**What is wrong?**

Remember that when I try to install the GTK and Glade `-dev` library's I got this error: `libgtk2.0-0 (=2.12.9-3ubuntu5) but 2.12.9-4ubuntu3 is to be installed` and when I try to install the `libgtk2.0-0` by downloading it I got this error: `Error: A later version is already installed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, that's only one error: it didn't find the gtk headers. Do you have [libgtk2.0-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/libgtk2.0-dev) installed?

It's a separate package which contains the header files, and is not usually installed by default. You'll need it for compilation, even though the libraries are installed.

Comment: Please, see my comment at @James answer. Thanks

Comment: And when I download this package and try to install `the libgtk2.0-0` I got this error: `Error: A later version is already installed`

Comment: But did you install the `-dev` package containing the libraries and headers?

Comment: When I try to install the `-dev` I got that error in the comment of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+-2.0.pc`
> to the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable
>
> No package `gtk+-2.0` found
>
> Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libglade-2.0.pc`
> to the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable
>
> No package `libglade-2.0` found

It looks like it failed to find the `gtk+-2.0` and `libglade-2.0` packages.  Do you have them installed?  Did you try adding the paths to those packages to the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` like it says?

Comment: When I try to install both they say this: Depends: `libgtk2.0-0 (=2.12.9-3ubuntu5) but 2.12.9-4ubuntu3 is to be installed`